# Copy value from grandchildren if it exists, use null otherwise

Tags: json, jq

Given the JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "coding": [{
        "code": 1234,
        "system": "target"
    }, {
        "code": 5678,
        "system": "other"
    }]
}
```

I can select the value of "code" where the "system" is "target", thus:

```
{id: .id} + {"code": .coding[]? | select(.system=="target").code}
```

To produce:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "code": 1234
}
```

But if the object whose "system" value is "target" does not exist in the array, thus:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "coding": [{
        "code": 5678,
        "system": "other"
    }]
}
```

I want the following result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "code": null
}
```

However, my above jq produces an empty object. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` built-in yields `empty` unless at least one of its inputs meets the given criteria, and `empty` consumes almost anything around itself. Hence the empty result.

Instead, use the `first` built-in for alternating between the `code` value from the object where `system` is `target`, and `null`. This also covers some other cases you didn't mention explicitly.

```
{ id, code: first((.coding[]? | select(.system == "target") .code), null) }
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4GrAHU_GCe)</sup>